# Make a for-each with Mustache?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, mustache

Im trying to learn Mustache, but cant get this script to work, and the guides i have found on Google dont seem to cover this one.

```
<div id="test"> </div>
<script id="testtpl" type="text/template">
    {{#sheet}}
      {{#.}}    
        {{a}}
      {{/.}}
    {{/sheet}}         
</script>

<script>
  var testing = {
    sheet: {
      'fur': {a: 6, b: 2, item: ['bold']},
      'bur': {a: 6, b: 2, item: ['bold']}
    }
  };
  $(function() {
    var template = $('#testtpl').html();
    var html = Mustache.to_html(template, testing);
    $('#test').html(html);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you defined `sheet and .` helpers ?

Comment: I dont know. Tried all kind of "dots" but cant get it to work

Comment: `{{ #sheet }}{{ a }}{{ /sheet }}` should do it, no?

Comment: Thats what i thought too, but no :(
If i do {{ #sheet }}{{ fur.a }}{{ /sheet }} i do get the value of fur.a, but then the hole idee behind this is ruined. I want it to list all of my a's

Comment: To iterate over sheet using #each, it must be an array. Otherwise you have to write your own helper.

Comment: Oh. I have no idee how to do that

Comment: Check my latest answer. I have tried to give you a platform where you can try something and get what you want. I suggest you to get some basics first. Read documentation from http://handlebarsjs.com/ It is not a big one..Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this

## Handlebars Template

```
{{#eachProp sheet}}
  {{this}}
{{/eachProp}}
```

## Context or javascript Literal

```
{
    sheet: {
      'fur': {a: 1, b: 2, item: ['bold']},
      'bur': {a: 5, b: 2, item: ['bold']}
    }
}
```

## Handlebars Helper

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('eachProp', function(context, options) {
  var data,
    out = [];

   console.log(context);

   for (var key in context) {
     out.push(context[key].a);
   }

   out = out.join(',');

  return out;
});
```

Try these blocks on [Try Handlebars](http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/). Now play around with this on the site and get whatever you want. Hope this helps!!